# How to hang off of wide circular hole in concrete?

Tags: hanging, hole, bolts

I have a concrete wall with many 2-inch diameter, 1.5 inch deep, perfectly cylindrical holes on it. I’d like to hang some relatively lightweight (up to 10 lbs) decorative stuff off of these holes. What type of bolt can I use to secure an item to one of these holes?

I imagine there might be a type of bolt that expands outwards and secures itself to the walls of the cylindrical hole.

Answer (score 3):

Appearance aside (perhaps your less than 10 lb items will cover the hanging point) plumbing test plugs come to mind. Exposed face commonly seen red, yellow and shiny galvanized steel. Two plates are squeezed together by a screw and cause a rubber part between to expand outward and grip the hole. Advantage being they are easily removed and no permanent damage/change to the wall.

If you don't mind an alteration to the wall of a more permanent nature, gluing 2" diameter discs of wood or some other substance you can easily put a screw into in the holes will make it easy to screw in whatever. Unfortunately I'm pretty sure that hockey pucks are a larger diameter than that. Yep, 3 inch diameter.

[image: test plug]

Comment: An excellent, simple, easy to implement solution. The hockey puck idea is good too, as too-large can be made smaller, while too-small is often harder to enlarge.